# Hibernate select inserted value and then insert in join table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is dummy code example to show my problem.

I have two entities with relation ManyToMany.

```
@Entity
public class Class implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2721854845989429844L;

  @Id
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  private UUID id;

  private String name;

  public UUID getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1203104744560316339L;

  @Id
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  private UUID id;

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer number;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "student_class",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_number", referencedColumnName = "number"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Class> classes;

  public UUID getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Integer getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(Integer number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Set<Class> getClasses() {
    return classes;
  }

  public void setClasses(Set<Class> classes) {
    this.classes = classes;
  }
}
```

The Join Table references Student by its number, which is auto generated by MySQL and references Class by its id.

When I try to insert a Student with classes hibernate tries to insert record in student_class directly after inserting row in student table, but student number is generated after the insert and then throws exception that column student_number can not be null.

How can I tell hibernate to select generated value in join column before doing insert in join table?

The class that contains the logic has the following code.
Where classRepository and studentRepository are interfaces that extends springs CrudRepository. There is no custom code in them.

```
    Class class1 = new Class();
    class1.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    class1.setName("Math");
    classRepository.save(class1);

    Class class2 = new Class();
    class2.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    class2.setName("Chemistry");
    classRepository.save(class2);

    Set<Class> classes = new HashSet<>();
    classes.add(class1);
    classes.add(class2);

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    student.setName("Student 1");
     student.setClasses(classes);

    studentRepository.save(student);
```

Console output:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.perksCamp.hello.Class */ select
        class0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        class0_.name as name2_0_0_ 
    from
        class class0_ 
    where
        class0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.perksCamp.hello.Class
        */ insert 
        into
            class
            (name, id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.perksCamp.hello.Class */ select
        class0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        class0_.name as name2_0_0_ 
    from
        class class0_ 
    where
        class0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.perksCamp.hello.Class
        */ insert 
        into
            class
            (name, id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.perksCamp.hello.Student */ select
        student0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        student0_.name as name2_1_0_,
        student0_.number as number3_1_0_ 
    from
        student student0_ 
    where
        student0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.perksCamp.hello.Student
        */ insert 
        into
            student
            (name, number, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row com.perksCamp.hello.Student.classes */ insert 
        into
            student_class
            (student_number, class_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
2018-04-07 12:42:44.268  WARN 5508 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2018-04-07 12:42:44.268 ERROR 5508 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'student_number' cannot be null
2018-04-07 12:42:44.268  INFO 5508 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-04-07 12:42:44.362 ERROR 5508 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'student_number' cannot be null
```

Comment: And why don't you just normalize your schema, and use the ID of the student as foreign key rather than its number?

Comment: This code is just to show the problem. In reality I have a different entities and id can not be used.

Comment: *id can not be used*: the question is why. That's exactly what IDs are for.